# How to load Native API in windows?

Tags: c

I wanted to find the address of some of API like NtUserMessageCall by using GetProcAddress.
But this error appears: "The specified procedure could not be found."

```
HMODULE hUser32 = LoadLibrary(TEXT("User32.dll"));//handle user32
LPCSTR APIName = "NtUserMessageCall";
FARPROC function_address = GetProcAddress(hNtdll, APIName);//retrun Null
int temp = GetLastError();//Error 127
hUser32 = GetModuleHandle(TEXT("User32.dll"));//retrun Null
temp = GetLastError();//Error 127
```

Comment: can you Please explain more?

Comment: why do you use user32 as ntdll? Wrong module

Comment: It's necessary for my job

Comment: To use Windows APIs you shouldn't load DLL files directly while Windows-SDK is provided in many compilers. For example in VS or MinGW/GCC you just need to `#include <windows.h>`.

Comment: I know but I want to use native API directly like in above.

Answer (score 0):

`user32.dll` does not export `NtUserMessageCall` for public use (it is internal only), so you cannot get its address by name using `GetProcAddress`. You'll have to find another technique, like downloading and parsing the symbol file (`.PDB`) for the version of the DLL you're working with.

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Should be set up like:

```
typedef unsigned __int64 QWORD;
typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* _NtUserMessageCall)(
HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, DWORD, DWORD, QWORD);

char sNtUserMessageCall[] = { 'N', 't', 'U', 's', 'e', 'r', 'M', 'e', 's', 's', 'a', 'g', 'e', 'C', 'a', 'l', 'l', 0x0 };

static auto NtUserMessageCall = (_NtUserMessageCall)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW("Ntdll.dll"), sNtUserMessageCall);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).